# how to solve ERROR TypeError: labels.slice is not a function?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am graphing a table with chartjs, when I do a first query it graphs me without problem but when I try to graph again, the same values or a different one shows me that error

```js
this.listadoResultadoGrafico.forEach((item: any) => {
  if (this.aux[item.pro_des]) {
    this.aux[item.pro_des].push(item);
  } else {
    this.aux[item.pro_des] = [item];
  }
  this.aux[item.pro_des].sort((a, b) => a.fecha - b.fecha);
})

const labels = new Set();
Object.keys(this.aux).map(key => {
  this.aux[key].map((item) => {
    labels.add(item.fecha);
  });
});

const color = this.helpersService.randomColor();
const datasets = Object.keys(this.aux).map(key => ({
  label: key,
  backgroundColor: color,
  borderColor: color,
  fill: false,
  data: this.aux[key].map((item) => item.monto_moneda_norm)
}));
console.log({
  labels,
  datasets
})
console.log(labels.size)

this.datosGrafico = {
  labels: labels,
  datasets: datasets,
};

this.titulos = this.titulosGrilla;

// Configuraciones correspondientes al gráfico.
this.opcionesGrafico = {
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  legend: {
    display: false,
  },
  elements: {
    line: {
      tension: 0,
    },
  },
};

this.auxData = {
  type: 'line',
  options: this.opcionesGrafico,
  //data : datasets,
  data: {
    labels: [...labels].map((value) => this.helpersService.transformDate(value, 'dd/MM/yyyy')),
    datasets
  },
};
```

```html
<div class="chart-container bottom-margin">
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

[image: ErrorFront]

```
 if (this.grafico) {
            this.grafico.data = this.datosGrafico;
            document.getElementById('chart-legends').innerHTML = this.grafico.generateLegend();
            this.grafico.update();
} else {
            this.grafico = new Chart('canvas', this.auxData);
 document.getElementById('chart-legends').innerHTML = this.grafico.generateLegend();
}
```

This is the error line. Of course, when I consult for the first time, it goes directly to the else because the graph does not exist, but when I consult again, it enters the if, and there I do not know how to interpret that error or, rather, to solve it.

Comment: You haven't included the code here that uses `.slice`

Comment: @Samathingamajig `.slice` is used within the chart.js library, as you can see in the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chart.js expects the `labels` property to be an array.
But your `labels` is a `Set` object, which can't use `slice`.

One way to fix this, would be to use an array instead of a set.

Another way would be getting an array from the set like this:

```
this.datosGrafico = {
  labels: Array.from(labels),
  datasets: datasets,
};
```

But I would suggest to just use an array instead of a set.

Comment: It works with the example that you shared with me, but when consulting again the values of the graph they modify, consulting with the same table.
first query.
`[
    247,
    260,
    256,
    256,
    265
],`
second query.
`[
    247,
    247,
    260,
    260,
    256,
    256,
    256,
    256,
    265,
    265
]`

Comment: Looks to me like you the values are put into the set a second time. You need to make sure, that it is an empty Set/Array, before adding the values.